# config.json Not Being Found on ASP.NET Core Startup in Debug

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have created a basic WebAPI project via Yeoman (note: I have this same issue with a "real" project I am working on, but `yo` demonstrates the problem as well) targeted at `netcoreapp1.0` on OSX.

On the command line, it restores, builds, and runs fine via `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build`, `dotnet run`.

When I am in Visual Studio Code and use Debug, however, I always receive the error: `"The configuration file 'config.json' was not found and is not optional."` which points at the first line of my `Main` method.

Here is my `Program.cs` entry point:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Here is `project.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "WebAPIApplication"
  }
}
```

Adding `Startup.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebAPIApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

If any other information is required, please let me know and I would be happy to add it.

As Gerardo suggested, printing out `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` I get two different outputs.

From command line (which works): `~/Projects/Path/WebApiApplication/`
From debug in VSCode: `~/Projects/Path`

What I also noticed is that output is going to `~/Projects/Path/WebApiApplication/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/` but no files are going with it (including `config.json`).

Comment: Does your Startup class contains something like  `new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("Config.json")` ?

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli It does, yes. I'll add Startup.cs to my question.

Comment: The `ConfigurationBuilder` is using paths relative to `.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath`, which cames from `Main`'s `.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`. So: could it be that VS Code debugging start your application on a different directory ?  Please add this `Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` as first line in `Main` and compare the output between 'dotnet run' and VS Code Debug.

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli Thanks. Definitely gave some interesting information. Put details in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like `dotnet run` is being run standing on the project folder and works correctly, but `VS Code` debug-mode is not.

This is configured in `VS Code` in a config file `.vscode\launch.json`.
Find the line that says:

```
       "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
```

and change it to:

```
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/MyProjectFolder",
```

You need to change the startup folder (`cwd`) so that it matches the location of your `project.json`/`config.json`/ etc.

More Info here: [Visual Studio Code Launch Configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations)

Comment: When you mentioned `.vscode\launch.json` I realized - I am opening a folder that is a step higher than many projects I have (some are libraries of others). This means there is a top-level `.vscode\launch.json`. If I open just the project I am looking to use, Debug works great. I guess this leads me to another question - how do I properly bring in other libraries that are part of the project in VSCode? Either way, marking your answer as good because it did get me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried editing the `launch.json` file as I suggested on the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Move .vscode folder INSIDE of **"YourSolution/src/YourProject"** directory, by mistake opened the project in VSCode in YourSolution directory and by tweaking configuration like the suggested answer ran the application, but with configuration problems.

So in VSCode you have to open the project from inside YourProject and default config will run properly.